# How can I redirect users to a login page after a timeout using C# in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I’m working on an ASP.NET program with the code behind in C# and connected to a SQL Server database.  I want to create a timeout that sends them to the logout page after a certain number of minutes.  I’m not using session timeout because the timeout value will vary based on the user’s role.  The .aspx page has an UpdatePanel with a DetailsView that has a BoundField for the TimeOut in epoch seconds and another BoundField for the CurrentEpochSecond.  These fields are from the database using a select statement.  A second DetailsView contains a TemplateField that shows the TimeLeft using a SqlDataSource statement that selects the TimeOut minus the CurrentEpochSecond as TimeLeft.    This is triggered by an AJAX timer every 60 seconds and TimeLeft value is shown in the DetailsView.

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DV_LoggedInTimeExpires" runat="server"  
DataSourceID="SDS_LoggedInTimeExpires" Height="50px" Width="125px" 
AutoGenerateRows="False" ondatabound="DV_LoggedInTimeExpires_DataBound" 
    onitemupdated="DV_LoggedInTimeExpires_ItemUpdated">
<Fields>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TimeLeft" SortExpression="TimeLeft">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="TimeLeftLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TimeLeft") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SDS_LoggedInTimeExpires" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT ESET - CRET AS TimeLeft FROM aspnet_Users WHERE 
(UserId = @UserId)" 
    onselecting="SDS_LoggedInTimeExpires_Selecting" 
    ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" >
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="UserId" Type="Object" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

In the C# code, I’ve tried several statements.  When I put

```
protected void DV_LoggedInTimeExpires_ItemUpdated(object sender, 
DetailsViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
  if (TimeLeft < 1)
    {
      Response.Redirect("~/Logout.aspx");
    }
}
```

VS shows an error that says: “The name 'TimeLeft' does not exist in the current context”

When I define TimeLeft as an int and change it to

```
protected void DV_LoggedInTimeExpires_ItemUpdated(object sender, 
DetailsViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
  int TimeLeft;
  if (TimeLeft < 1)
    {
      Response.Redirect("~/Logout.aspx");
    }
}
```

VS shows an error that says: “Use of unassigned local variable 'TimeLeft'”.

Comment: Hi, you would need to share more code. Because "TImeLeft" just doesn't exist.

Comment: The specific error you describe would disappear if you did `int TimeLeft = 0;`. It throws an error because you did not assign a value to the variable.

Comment: Jesse is right. How did you expect it to calculate whether TimeLeft less than 1 or not when TimeLeft doesn't have a value? It's nonsenical. In C#, variables don't have a value until you give them one. Perhaps this is different to some other language you have used previously?

Comment: You could do this with FormsAuthentication by creating a FormsAuthenticationTicket whose expiry depends on the user's role: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_Security_FormsAuthenticationTicket__ctor_System_String_System_Boolean_System_Int32_